# What does $\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}^{-1}$ converge to (if it converges)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, summation

How we can show if the sum of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{{n \choose k}}$$ converges and then find the result of the sum if it converges?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{\binom{n}{k}}
&=2+\frac2n+\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}\frac1{\binom{n}{k}}
\end{align}
$$
However
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}\frac1{\binom{n}{k}}
&\le\frac{n-3}{\binom{n}{2}}\\
&=\frac{2(n-3)}{n(n-1)}\\[9pt]
&\to0
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{\binom{n}{k}}=2
$$

Answer (score 5):

For every $n\geqslant4$, the two extreme terms are $\frac11$, the two terms next to them are $\frac1n$ and each of the remaining $n-3$ terms is at most $\frac2{n(n-1)}$, hence the $n$th sum $S_n$ is such that
$$
2\leqslant S_n\leqslant2+\frac2n+\frac2{n(n-1)}(n-3)\lt2+\frac4n.
$$
In particular, $S_n\to2$.

Comment: we were scooped years ago :-)